# Unreasonably large memory use with high-res screenshot script

Tags: unity, c#, memory-efficiency, memory, screenshot

I'm using this piece of code to save renders and I'm saving renders in every frame inside `Update()`.

Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System;

//getty code
public class Capture : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static int resWidth = 3840;
    private static int resHeight = 2160;
    private static GameObject camObj = null;


    public static string ScreenShotName()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}/screenshots/{1}.png",
                             Application.dataPath,
                             Util.name_);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        camObj = gameObject;
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.dataPath + "/screenshots");
        resHeight=GetComponent<Camera>().pixelHeight;
        resWidth=GetComponent<Camera>().pixelWidth;
        //Util.everyThingHot = true;
    }

    public static void TakeHiResShot()
    {
        try
        {
            RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(resWidth, resHeight, 24);
            camObj.GetComponent<Camera>().targetTexture = rt;

            Texture2D screenShot = new Texture2D(resWidth, resHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
            camObj.GetComponent<Camera>().Render();
            RenderTexture.active = rt;
            screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidth, resHeight), 0, 0);
            camObj.GetComponent<Camera>().targetTexture = null;
            RenderTexture.active = null;
            Destroy(rt);
            byte[] bytes = screenShot.EncodeToPNG();
            string filename = ScreenShotName();
            File.WriteAllBytes(filename, bytes);
            Debug.Log(string.Format("Took screenshot to: {0}", filename));
            bytes = null;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("Error");
        }

    }

}
```

This is giving me 4K images.

But the problem is, it's taking a lot of memory. I have 8 Gigs and it's using 95% of it.

[image]

I'm quite sure that it shouldn't take this much memory. I should free up the memory. How can I achieve that. I know *.Net* has it's own garbage collector, but before it works, it takes so much memory.

**So how to do it manually?**

I added `GC.Collect()`, but no good and it even hangs. Previously it used to take like 2-3 minutes to occupy 95%, now it takes only 30 seconds or less.

I used this code :

```
RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(resWidth, resHeight, 24);
        camObj.GetComponent<Camera>().targetTexture = rt;

        Texture2D screenShot = new Texture2D(resWidth, resHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        camObj.GetComponent<Camera>().Render();
        RenderTexture.active = rt;
        screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidth, resHeight), 0, 0);
        camObj.GetComponent<Camera>().targetTexture = null;
        RenderTexture.active = null;
        rt = null;

        Destroy(rt);
        byte[] bytes = screenShot.EncodeToPNG();
        string filename = ScreenShotName();
        File.WriteAllBytes(filename, bytes);
        bytes = null;
        screenShot = null;

        GC.Collect();
```

I also added after calling this method:

```
Capture.TakeHiResShot();
GC.Collect();
```

[image]

After changing :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System;

public class Capture : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static int resWidth = 3840;
    private static int resHeight = 2160;
    private static GameObject camObj = null;
    private static RenderTexture rt;
    private static Texture2D screenShot;
    private static byte[] bytes;


    public static string ScreenShotName()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}/screenshots/{1}.png",
                             Application.dataPath,
                             Util.name_);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        camObj = gameObject;
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.dataPath + "/screenshots");
        rt = new RenderTexture(resWidth, resHeight, 24);
        screenShot = new Texture2D(resWidth, resHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    }

    public static void TakeHiResShot()
    {
        try
        {
            camObj.GetComponent<Camera>().targetTexture = rt;
            camObj.GetComponent<Camera>().Render();
            RenderTexture.active = rt;
            screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidth, resHeight), 0, 0);
            camObj.GetComponent<Camera>().targetTexture = null;
            RenderTexture.active = null;
            Destroy(rt);
            bytes = screenShot.EncodeToPNG();
            string filename = ScreenShotName();
            File.WriteAllBytes(filename, bytes);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {   
            Debug.Log(e.Data);
        }

    }

}
```

Now its like this :

[image]

Profiler :

[image]

Comment: `GC.Collect();`

Comment: Please see the question again, i have tried that but no good.

Comment: If you do that every Update, you should avoid using `new`. Store your RenderTexture, Texture2D, arrays and everything that is of reference type in class fields and reuse them instead of creating and throwing away.

Comment: The task manger is a basic option for software inspection, but you should make sure you tackle the right issue by using the profiler.

Comment: In your latest edit, you destroy your `RenderTexture` after the first time you use it, meaning on subsequent frames it's `null` so `ReadPixels` tries to read from the main frame buffer instead. But the frame buffer is smaller (950 x 498 in this case), and not available to read from because your code is not running in the right part of the rendering loop to access it. Easy fix: don't `Destroy()` stuff you plan to re-use.

Comment: @DMGregory after doing so,  removing `Destroy()` it now takes very few amount of RAM

Comment: Calling `GC.Collect()` is rather highly not recommended. It is seldom we (programmers) know better than the runtime when to call it. :)

Answer (score 4):

`Textures`, `RenderTextures`, and `Materials` use memory outside of C#'s managed heap (including GPU memory), so the regular C# garbage collector alone can't fully clean them up.

You need to manually `Destroy()` them once you no longer need them.

Your current code does this for the `RenderTexture` `rt` (though it doesn't call [Release](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture.Release.html) first - I'm not sure if that's necessary) but it never destroys the `Texture2D` `screenshot`.

Since `screenshot` is readable CPU-side, that means it may be in memory twice: once in VRAM and once in main RAM. So every time you take a screenshot you're allocating something like:

```
(3840 x 2160) pixels x 3 bytes per pixel x 2 copies = 47.5 MiB
```

47.5 megs of memory that you never use again and never free. (We made this same mistake in one of the early prototypes on the Starlink project - it'd be nice to get better warnings about this!)

You can clean this up by remembering to `Destroy()` this texture too, but an even better solution is to "Reduce, Reuse, Recycle": if you're taking screenshots frequently, allocate the screenshot buffer once on start-up or lazily on first use, and keep re-using the same one. Something like this:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
public class Capture {

    // Let's give this a proper singleton implementation
    // if you want global access.
    static Capture instance;
    public static Capture instance {
        get {
            if(instance == null) {
                Debug.LogWarning("No Capture instance in this scene. Adding one to the default camera...");
                Camera.main.AddComponent<Capture>();
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    public Vector2Int resolution = new Vector2Int(3840, 2160);

    Camera camera;
    Texture2D screenshot;

    // Singleton implementation - remember where the current instance is.
    void Awake() {
        if(instance != null) {
            Debug.LogWarning("More than one Capture instance currently present. Destroying later one.");
            Destroy(this);
            return;
        }

        instance = this;
    }

    public void TakeScreenshot() {
        // Do this only once, the first time we take a screenshot.
        if(screenshot == null) {
            camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
            screenshot = new Texture2D(resolution.x, resolution.y, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        }

        // Get a temporary render texture from Unity's pool, rather than allocate our own.
        // This allows it to be re-used for other features when we're not using it.
        var rt = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(resolution.x, resolution.y, 24);

        // Draw the frame into our render texture.
        camera.targetTexture = rt;
        camera.Render();

        // Copy the render texture into our persistent CPU-side buffer.
        RenderTexture.active = rt;
        screenshot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resolution.x, resolution.y), 0, 0);

        // Put the camera/rendering state back the way we found it.
        camera.targetTexture = null;
        RenderTexture.active = null;        

        // Done with this! Let someone else use it, or clean it up if it goes unused.
        RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(rt);

        byte[] bytes = screenshot.EncodeToPNG();
        string filename = ScreenShotName();
        File.WriteAllBytes(filename, bytes);
    }

    // Clean up after ourselves when destroying this instance.
    void OnDestroy() {
        Destroy(screenshot);
    }
}
```

Summarizing my changes:

- I don't like mixing instance members like `camObject.GetComponent()` in a `static` context where `camObject` could be `null`, so I made this a singleton with `TakeScreenshot()` as a non-static method. This gives us better guarantees that everything runs sensibly, and better warnings when we make a mistake.

  You can still call this without knowing where the instance is by first asking for it:

  `Capture.instance.TakeScreenshot()`
- One `Texture2D` is created lazily when taking the first screenshot (so in runs where you take no screenshots, no memory needs to be allocated), and is re-used for the life of this camera. When the capture script is destroyed (eg. on scene unload), it destroys the texture properly.

  If you want, you could re-use the texture between scenes too, particularly if you fix your resolution as a constant that can't change between scenes.
- Instead of creating our own `RenderTexture`, we ask Unity's rendering system to furnish us with a temporary one, then release the temporary when we're done.

  This can be a good habit to get into with render targets - especially if you have a bunch of effects using the screen's resolution - because it lets the same memory be re-used by multiple operations.

  Unity will handle allocating the memory if it doesn't have a spare temporary of the requested size/format, and de-allocating it once the target goes unused for a little while.

Answer (score 2):

I finally used this code :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System;

public class Capture : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static int resWidth = 3840;
    private static int resHeight = 2160;
    private static GameObject camObj = null;

    private static RenderTexture rt;

    private static Texture2D screenShot;


    public static string ScreenShotName()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}/screenshots/{1}.png",
                             Application.dataPath.Substring(0,Application.dataPath.LastIndexOf('/')),
                             Util.name_);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        camObj = gameObject;
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.dataPath.Substring(0,Application.dataPath.LastIndexOf('/')) + "/screenshots");
        rt = new RenderTexture(resWidth, resHeight, 24);

        screenShot = new Texture2D(resWidth, resHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    }

    public static void TakeHiResShot()
    {
        try
        {
            camObj.GetComponent<Camera>().targetTexture = rt;

            camObj.GetComponent<Camera>().Render();
            RenderTexture.active = rt;
            screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidth, resHeight), 0, 0);
            camObj.GetComponent<Camera>().targetTexture = null;
            RenderTexture.active = null;
            byte[] bytes = screenShot.EncodeToPNG();
            string filename = ScreenShotName();
            File.WriteAllBytes(filename, bytes);
            bytes = null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Debug.Log(e.Data);
        }

    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        Destroy(rt);
        Destroy(screenShot);
    }

}
```

And everything was cool less than 150 MB of RAM was used, although it had a spike of 300 MB at first.

Thanks to all who helped.